# How can I get the build number of my Android app?

Tags: android, android-manifest

How can I get the build number of my Android app and setText to a textview?

For example, "Build # 91".

Comment: Which build system are you using? What do you mean by build number? (version code?)

Comment: No i don't need the version number, i need the number of build of the app. The textview should change according to the build of the app.

Comment: I need to get the build. For example "Build # 91". Please anyone help for this.

Answer (score 7):

Simple and short way: implement into your activity

```
String versionName = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
.getPackageInfo(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv); 
tv.setText(versionName);
```

Comment: But it is used to get the version number right? I need the Build number.

Comment: @user3098684 what u want?

Comment: So, you really mean versionCode! Just replace versionName with versionCode in the proposed answer. TheHippo already pointed this out, correctly (first comment to your question).

Comment: No..We have build for each app right? When we make any changes in that each time it create a different build.

Comment: I need to get the build. For example "Build # 91". Please anyone help for this.

Comment: @user3098684 where u got from?